# $route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] on routes giving me 404 page not found Error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have just started working with codeigniter, Working in admin control panel of my small project. Getting 404 page not found Error when i am trying to edit or delete.

In routes.php `$route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';` its giving me 404 Error.

If i access `$route['admin/clients/update'] = 'admin_clients/update';`, its loading edit form.If i pass segement 4 in url  its giving me 404 page Not found Error.

here is my htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testing_palace/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Am not getting what exact problem is.Please help me, response will be appreciated

Comment: if this works /index.php/admin/clients/update/yourparams than you have to change index_page in config and use site_url from where you are redirecting to update link

Comment: @krish even  /index.php/admin/clients/update/yourparams its not working giving me the same error.

Comment: $route['admin/clients/update/(:num)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';
try this..

Comment: @akhilClement its also not working.

Comment: i think it's the issue of .htacess file try with 
 RewriteEngine off  mode...

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the order of your route definitions.

For example

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';
$route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin/clients/$1';
$route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';
```

will always catch the first rule, and `admin/clients/update/1` will look to `admin/clients/update/1` and because of this, it may give a 404 error.

but like this:

```
$route['admin/clients/update/(:any)'] = 'admin_clients/update/$1';
$route['admin/clients/(:any)'] = 'admin/clients/$1';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';
```

every rule will be checked until a valid rule, so `admin/clients/update/1` will redirect to `admin_clients/update/1`.